NTFS-3g auto mount on boot on MacOS -
etc/fstab:
/dev/disk4s1 /Volumes/HDD /usr/local/bin/ntfs-3g local,allow_other,auto_xattr 0 0

sudo mount -a:
ntfs-3g % sudo mount -a
mount_apfs: volume could not be mounted: Permission denied
mount: / failed with 66

but if I manually in terminal run sudo ntfs-3g /dev/disk4s1 /Volumes/HDD -o local -o allow_other -o auto_xattr then it mounts the disk without any issues.
not sure why does it tries to use apfs

The third field in fstab is not the name of a binary to execute to mount the filesystem.  It is the fstype.

@MarcWilson so it's not possible in other ways? I tried LaunchDaemons to start sh script to unmount disk and mount with ntfs-3g (script path specified in plist) but it fails with disk error permission, only unmount command works fine before mounting with ntfs-3g, but If I directly launch sh script from terminal, it works fine - unmounts disk and mounts with ntfs-3g right away

Couldn't tell you or I'd offer an answer.  I've used Paragon NTFS for years.

@MarcWilson does it work stable to boot even before you login to macos? for example to run mac mini 24/7 as SMB/DLNA Media server?

You wouldn't need NTFS in order to do that.

@MarcWilson I know, I just wanted to use an existing NTFS HDD which already has files and keep it compatible for Windows. But yeah, I have already decided to buy another disk to format it in native apple file system

The third field is the filesystem, so should be specified as ntfs-3g without the full path.
Try updating your /etc/fstab line to:
/dev/disk4s1 /Volumes/HDD ntfs-3g local,allow_other,auto_xattr 0 0


Does that require there to be a mount_ntfs-3g binary?

You need to have the package installed so the driver is there an can be used, which would mean the binary exists as well.
